newpax and pdfpages: include bookmarks of subdocuments in maindocument
Using the pdfpages package we can include whole PDF documents in our new maindocument. I will call the documents to be included "sub-pdfs" and the new maindocument "archive-document".
Using the package newpax the sub-pdfs can keep their internal links, including the table of contents with clickable links and bookmarks, in the archive-document. Without newpax, you can include the sub-pdfs as well, but without links and bookmarks.
I provide MWEs for the minimal setup:
The sub-pdfs 1 and 2 were compiled at an earlier time, I need to include the PDF in my archive document. You can create the sub-pdf No. 1 with this code (name: docsec1.tex):
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{ToBe Included Doc No 1}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

\tableofcontents{}

\blinddocument

\end{document}

And of sub-pdf No. 2 (name: docsec2.tex):
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{ToBe Included Doc No 2}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

\tableofcontents{}

\blinddocument

\end{document}

The code of my archive-document (name: DocArchive.tex), which has to be compiled using luatex:
\DocumentMetadata{pdfstandard=A-2b, pdfversion=1.7}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pdfpages, newpax}

\directlua{require("newpax")}
\directlua
{
  newpax.writenewpax("docsec1")
  newpax.writenewpax("docsec2")
}
\newpaxsetup{usefileattributes=true, addannots=true, dests=all}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Archive of other documents}
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

\tableofcontents{}

\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{docsec1},docsec1}]{docsec1}

\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{docsec2},docsec2}]{docsec2}
\end{document}

The toc of the PDF DocArchive.pdf consists of two entries: docsec1 and docsec2. Both are on chapter level. The included documents docsec1 and docsec2 still have working tables of contents with clickable links, thanks to the package newpax.
Question: Is there a way to get the toc entries of the sub-pdfs as section, subsection, whatever entries into the toc of the archive-document automagically?
Probably this would be helpful for compilations. More and more PDF documents come with bookmarks. I'm thinking about a kind of structured archives of multiple PDFs, which would be much easier to handle if they came with a "central" table of contents.
I'm aware that I could simply use \input{docsec1.tex}. But often you don't have the TeX-code of a PDF or the PDF might have been produced without TeX, but nonetheless have bookmarked sections.
UPDATE
The picture below shows a screenshot from my pdfviewer (okular). At the left hand border is a table of contents, but not the printed toc of the pdf, as to be seen on the displayed page 2 on the right side.

If I could have the equivalent entries from the included sub-pdfs there, in the left hand sided toc made by the viewer.
I'm on the way to develop digital court files, or better: digital lawyers files. You know, we always have two parties, sometimes more. Instead of 800 pages printouts I'd prefer a well structured digital file and thus I need the bookmarks of the tocs I include.
Except from my usecase, I guess that document archives would be very helpfull if pdfpages could add their section entries to the main entry:
\includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={1,chapter,1,{Document of may 24}, may-24-doc, includetocentries=yes}]{docsec1}

The option includetocentries= is what I could use.
By the way, I'd ask chatGPT to add an addtotoc-entry for each section in a given pdf, but I can't do that in reality without revealing clients data to chatGPT.

In your exampel the TOC is just "normal text with normal links". Apart from the link name (hyperref uses names like "subsection.1.2" there's no way to distinguish these links from any other link in the PDF. So you would have to come up with a heuristic that finds these special links. Another way would be to create a tagged PDF that has special TOC-elements. But I'm unaware about the current state of tagged PDF and newpax.

As far (well, as short) as I understand, a tagged PDF will have tags on sections. So the combination of a section tag with a hyperlink may, well, not solve, but be a basis to spot the right hyperlink. The tagpdf package has, thanks to the unfailing author, reached version 0.99b. But I'm afraid it would need more than a rainy weekend to get a draft version of an enhanced pdfpages running. However, thank you very much for that package!

@AndreasMatthias newpax currently doesn't extract or use structure elements from a tagged PDF and I doubt that this would solve the problem, as it is would be difficult to reverse engineer the \contentsline code from the content in the PDF. The same is true for the bookmarks: one could extract them but it would need quite some heuristic to deduce a toc from it. Imho the problem could only be solved if the included PDF contain the needed data embedded as tex source (or if the toc-files are available in some other way).

generally the question is rather unclear: do you only want to restore the bookmarks or also a printed  tableofcontents/toc?

@UlrikeFischer I tried to explain in an update.

In general this is a very complex subject, even if you restrict yourself to PDFs generated by LaTeX. And the more I ponder on this, the more questions arise.
Anyway, if you have the .toc files of the sub-documents, then you can read them in and try to recycle the \contensline entries.
I don't have a general or even flexible solution. The following is more of an experiment tailored specifically to your example. But it seems to work in this case.
File article-1.tex:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Aaa}\blindtext[2]
\subsection{Bbb}\blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{Ccc}\blindtext[2]
\section{Ddd}\blindtext[2]
\subsection{Eee}\blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{Fff}\blindtext[2]
\end{document}

File article-2.tex:
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Ggg}\blindtext[2]
\subsection{Hhh}\blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{Iii}\blindtext[2]
\section{Jjj}\blindtext[2]
\subsection{Kkk}\blindtext[2]
\subsubsection{Lll}\blindtext[2]
\end{document}

File main.tex:
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{scrreport}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{newpax}
\directlua
{
  require("newpax")
  newpax.writenewpax("article-1")
  newpax.writenewpax("article-2")
}
\newpaxsetup{usefileattributes=true, addannots=true, dests=all}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\renewcommand \thesection {\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{1.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{2.2em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{3.1em}}
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{5em}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\define@key{pdfpages}{addsubtoc}{%
  \def\numberline##1{}%
  \def\addtotoc_bucket{}%
  \def\contentsline##1##2##3##4{%
    % The third parameter of addtotoc represents the section level. To simplify matters
    % we set section level = 1 which is actually wrong. Therefore secnumdepth won't work
    % correctly in the TOC.
    \tl_put_right:Nx\addtotoc_bucket{##3, ##1, 1, ##2, #1-##4,}}%
  \makeatletter
  \InputIfFileExists{#1.toc}{}{}%
  \tl_put_right:No\AM@toclist{\addtotoc_bucket}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\patchcmd\AM@split@optionsii
{\equal{addtotoc}}
{\equal{addtotoc}{\AM@temp}\or\equal{addsubtoc}}
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\includepdf[
  pages = -,
  addtotoc = {1, chapter, 0, Article 1, sec:art-1},
  addsubtoc = article-1
]{article-1.pdf}

\includepdf[
  pages = -,
  addtotoc = {1, chapter, 0, Article 2, sec:art-2},
  addsubtoc = article-2
]{article-2.pdf}

\end{document}

Note: Some packages, like babel, write specific commands into the *.toc file.
E.g.:
\babel@toc {german}{}\relax

If you are using such packages in your sub-documents (article-1.tex, ...),
then make sure that these commands are defined in your main document (main.tex)
as well, because your main document reads the *.toc files of all your sub-documents.
You should either include babel in your main document as well:
\usepackage[german]{babel}

Or provide your own definition, e.g. to cancel this command:
\newcommand\babel@toc[2]{}


Thank you very much! In my real life file I get an error "Package xkeyval Error: addsubtoc' undefined in families Gin'." I guess that means the \define@key... doesn't work. However, if a broader solution is out of reach, it's probably not worth any more time and effort.

Oh sorry, I forgot to patch in this new options. I've fixed it in my answer above. Now it should work.

Yes! Babel throws an ERROR: Undefined control sequence, l.1 \babel         @toc {ngerman}{}\relax, but nonetheless it works with an appropriate *.toc.

If you use packages, like babel, that write commands (here \babel@toc) into the toc-file of your sub-documents, then make sure that your main document knows how to handle these commands. Either you use babel in your main document as well, or you provide your own definitions of \babel@toc (e.g. a dummy definition to cancel this command).

I just had a look into the main document: yes, babel packge properly loaded and "ngerman" as option in options of the documentclass. I will test with your examples here and report. Feel happy to ignore...
